# How to connect firebase firestore to redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I have problems retrieving data from firebase firestore
Although I have assigned the product to the list_product variable, when console.log it is empty.
I think this is the asynchronous mechanism of js but I don't know how to fix it...

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionType'
import { firebaseApp } from '../constants/firebaseConfig'
import "@firebase/firestore"



var list_product = []
var db = firebaseApp.firestore()

db.collection("product").get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            list_product.push(doc.data())
        })
        console.log(list_product)
    })


var initialState = list_product

var myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.types) {
        case types.LIST_ALL_PRODUCT:
            return [...state];
        case types.SHOW_INFO_DETAIL_PRODUCT:
            return [...state];
        default:
            return [...state];
    }
}

export default myReducer;
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as text? Also please explain if you got any error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach another `.then()` to perform actions after the first `.then()` completes

```
db.collection("product").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
    list_product.push(document.data())
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log(list_product)
});
```

You could also use a Promise:

```
var bar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.collection("product").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
      list_product.push(document.data())
    });
    resolve("All Good")
  });
});

bar.then(() => {
  console.log(list_product)
});
```

If you still get no data, check if the query returns data with, for example, `console.log(querySnapshot.empty)`